# How to use global component in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6, angular2-services

I can not use multiple time in a component or inside other component i think may be multiple router issue? i do not know? it is working same time both.How to differentiate it?

Comment: only one router-outlet please, don't use two of those, that is a very bad design.

Comment: breadcrumb is global component so How we can use multiple time breadcrumb?

Comment: Multiple time means how we can use breadcrumb in another component?

Answer (score 0):

if you want it on app.component.html:

```
Test

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Answer (score 0):

First.

```
 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Must be **only once** in the entire applications, that's how angular works.

If you want to reuse a component a good way to do is using a **[module](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodules)**.

It took time, at the beggining but it worth the effort, cause you'll be **saving time** in **maintenance** you app.

A great way to understand it is by practice and to see how Ionic started.

[Ionic example](https://github.com/ionic-team/starters/tree/master/ionic-angular/official/super)

You can see my changes in your stackblitz.

Comment: I can not see your changes in my stackblitz

Comment: I did but changes doesn't save due bad connections, but know you got the foundation to start.

Comment: Please send me your changes..that is very useful me..pls send updated stackblitz link